# VBA MSXML2.XMLHTTP downloads different contents for same urls

Tags: excel, msxml, vba

Hello i am trying to open a URL in excel VBA using the below code

```
Public Sub downloadCode()
Dim xHttp As MSXML2.XMLHTTP
Dim hdoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim hElem As MSHTML.HTMLGenericElement
Set xHttp = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP
URL = Sheet8.Range("U3").value

If InStr(URL, "ebay.co.uk") = 0 Then
    MsgBox ("Invalid Ebay Link. Row:" & i)
    Exit Sub
End If

xHttp.Open "GET", URL
xHttp.send

Do
    DoEvents
Loop Until xHttp.ReadyState = 4

'put into an htmldocument object
Set hdoc = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
hdoc.body.innerHTML = xHttp.responseText
xHttp.abort
Dim MyFile1, fnum1
MyFile1 = "C:\hp\outputFromExcel1.txt"
fnum1 = FreeFile()
Open MyFile1 For Output As fnum1
Print #fnum1, hdoc.body.innerHTML
Close #fnum1
Shell "C:\WINDOWS\explorer.exe """ & MyFile1 & "", vbNormalFocus
End Sub
```

The url i am trying to download is:
http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Single-Charging-Station-Dock-for-Xbox-360-Controller-White-/150723862162?pt=UK_Chargers_Docks&hash=item2317d79e92

My browser is IE9 with Windows7, however it returns the right data on one PC, but a different one on another PC which has same configuration, what could be wrong? I opened the URL in the browser and it's HTML source is same for both of them.

Comment: maybe a stupid question - but what kind of difference is there?

Comment: As always, `MSXML2.XMLHTTP` refers to `MSXML2.XMLHTTP30`. To access the more recent MSXML6 version you need `MSXML2.XMLHTTP60` - details at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/xmlteam/archive/2006/10/23/using-the-right-version-of-msxml-in-internet-explorer.aspx Use the References dialog in Excel to check which version of MSXML is being used on each machine